# deny unauthorized users with an alert message

Tags: vb.net

net ,vb. I want to deny users who have not logged in with a message" you have to login to access this page".
Can someone help me write the code in vb.net?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server" ID="LoginView1">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <p>Please log in.</p>
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <p>You are logged in</p>
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: @onfire4JesusCollins tick the green box next to my answer, and optionally the Up Arrow :)